# Ethereum Web3.js returns "Cannot find module 'web3-requestManager'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to start using Ethereum Web3.js with node 6.11.1 on a macosx

I installed web3 with the following command:

> npm install web3

Then i launch this - apparently - simple node command:

> Web3 = require('web3');

Well, it returns the following error:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'web3-requestManager'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fremente/Dropbox/Influx Design/Web htdocs/ethereum/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-core/src/index.js:26:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

it looks like it require some module (e.g. 'web3-requestManager') that aren't installed with the package.

Here it is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ethereum",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "ethereumjs-testrpc": "^4.0.1",
    "solc": "^0.4.13",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Any Idea? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Just for completion, there is an open issue with this problem at the git repo for the library: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/966

Comment: I opened that issue 

Comment: I solved installing the 0.4 version

Comment: It was a package renaming issue, please add this in the .bashrc NODE_PATH=${HOME}/node_modules. and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem comes from using a beta version of web3 its not stable at the moment and currently is under heavy development you have one of two options,

- either use a stable version 0.23 i think or something like that
- or manually install all the needed dependencies i don't recommend this solution for a stable dapp since things are currently really unstable

Comment: It is very unstable at the moment, nonetheless I put together an example repo using `Web.js` `v1.0-beta18` that does work (it has the correct dependencies): https://github.com/leopoldjoy/react-ethereum-dapp-example

Comment: You are correct like I stated in the solution above you can manually install all dependencies and web3 v1.0 will work, however, I noticed some edge cases even after installing all dependencies, to be honest problems like these are a clear indicator that web 1.0v shouldn't be used currently for any production code.

Answer (score 16):

```
npm install ethereum/web3.js
```

should solve your problem

Comment: I had to use this first to clear that error above and then my meta mask account was not able to be found so I had to use web3@1.0.0-beta.34

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by removing `node_modules` folder, running `npm install` again and installing `web3js` manually in addition to `package.json` listing:

**Add dependency to package.json**

```
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.31"
```

**Rebuild modules**

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

**Install web3 manually**

```
npm install web3@1.0.0-beta.31
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing  git on my Windows 10 machine helped. Dependencies did not install properly without it. https://git-scm.com/downloads

Answer (score 2):

`npm install ethereum/web3.js` fixed my issue.

hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this exact issue with: `web3@1.0.0-beta.26`

I have fixed this issue by upgrading node from `v6.11.3` to `v8.9.4`.

I have removed `node_modules` folder and run: `npm install` to rebuild modules.

I think that web3 is using features that are only supported by node version 8.x.x.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the `web3-requestManager` issue by pinning to `1.0.0-beta.29` version. Previously it was installing `1.0.0-beta.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using web3 1.0 version. And I am using macOS as well.  If you are using this version too, try this:

```
Running npm install ethereum/web3.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading "react-scripts" from "5.0.0" to "4.0.3" did the trick for me.

Comment: Hello, please consider this question is more than 4 years old, the versions you're mentioning don't really match OP's environment.